# Need help with Visual Force and a Mail Merge Word Document

Tags: visualforce, contact, professional-edition, mail-merge

Just upgraded to Office 365 and unfortunately Salesforce native MailMerge functionality is not supported. We are an operation of 3 users on a Professional Edition. So most Apps are needing Enterprise edition or its pricey. I read online there is a way to do it through Visual Force. Can someone help me? The Mail Merge is on a Contact Object, would like to see if I can output it to Word Or PDF using a button on a Contact page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ask Salesforce to activate extended mail merge. It's free and can be used with Professional.